# How to disable child elements within an element that has attribute disabled in Polymer?

Tags: html, polymer, disabled-input, recursive-datastructures

Which are elegant ways to disable children, if at least one of parent elements has an attribute disabled?

I have form fields which are nested within groups, where each the groups and the fields can be disabled depending on the values of other fields. Multiple parents can be disabled independent of each other.
Of course, I could query select and iteratively disable the children i.e. fields of a recently disabled parent. But to reactivate the fields I also have to iterate all the fields that are no longer within any disabled parent.

Or is it better to register an event on each parent? The structure has an assumed depth of 3 with about 100 elements.

A parent form field or an attribute aria-disabled would disable child fields, but that's no option since paper-elements are not aware of that.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A bit of a creative solution is to create two input elements one with the attribute `disabled` set and the other without it and then show/hide them depending on whether a parent has the `disabled` attribute set.

```css
* /deep/ input[disabled] {
  display: none;
}

[disabled] /deep/ input[disabled] {
  display: initial; /* or inline */
}

[disabled] /deep/ input:not([disabled]) {
  display: none;
}
```

I haven't used `:not()` yet. If this doesn't work you can set an attribute `enabled` on the enabled input element and use

```css
[disabled] /deep/ input:[enabled] {
  display: none;
}
```

I have not tested the solution but I guess it should work but I don't know if you are interested in this kind of solution anyway.

Comment: If I understand correctly, your answer states to have two fields for every binding. I like that your approach is no effort on the JS side. But whether it's elegant to hold every field twice is arguable. Thanks! Sometimes it also helps to consider problems from different directions.

Comment: Exactly. The second input does nothing and has no binding but it has to be there and which one of the two is visible is controlled by CSS. This is the only solution I can think of without using `querySelectorAll(...).forEach(...)` (Dart code, I don't know JS well but I guess you know what I mean) because the `disabled` attribute can't be inherited.